# SQL query to display table data as per requirement

Tags: sql, oracle

Can you please suggest how to display below data as per requirement.

Table (XX) data:

```
id  type amount
--- ---- -----
1    A     23.0
2    A     12.0
3    A     34.0
4    B     17.0
5    B     16.0
6    B     20.0
```

Requirement : I want to display output as below

```
type A amount   type B amount
-------------   -------------
23.0             17.0
12.0             16.0
34.0             20.0
```

I have tried below query but it is fetching duplicate rows

```
select a.amount,b.amount 
from xx,(select * from xx where type='A')a,(select * from xx where type='B')b
where xx.id=a.id and xx.id=b.id
```

Comment: How do you know that `23.0` belongs in the same output row like `17.0`? To me it looks like you are creating pairs with no obvious connection.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pain.  You seem to want to put the values as "lists" in each column.  This isn't really the SQL-way, but it is possible:

```
select max(a.value) as a, max(b.value) as b
from (select xx.*, rownum as seqnum
      from xx
      where type = 'A'
     ) a full outer join
     (select xx.*, rownum as seqnum
      from xx
      where type = 'B'
     ) b
     on a.seqnum = b.seqnum
group by coalesce(a.seqnum, b.seqnum);
```

You can add `order by id` to the subqueries if you want to preserve the original ordering.

EDIT:

Note, another way of doing this uses `union all`:

```
select max(a) as a, max(b) as b
from ((select rownum as seqnum, value as a, NULL as b from xx where type = 'A'
      ) union all
      (select rownum as seqnum, NULL, value from xx where type = 'B'
      )
     ) ab
group by seqnum;
```

Comment: can you run the query with sample data instead giving assumed query

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon Linoff..i knew this is not the correct way but the requirement is like that..anyways thanks a lot.

Comment: i ran the query and it is working as per the requirement.

Comment: both sql queries are working fine..Excellent Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 1):

If the number of A's always are the same as the number of B's, and the A's always are first:

```
select ta.amount as "table A amount",
       tb.amount as "table B amount"
from tablename ta
  join tablename tb on ta.id + (select count(*) from tablename) / 2 = tb.id
```

Comment: if the data Is going to change 1 more column for A or B then it wont work

Comment: @mohan111. That's why I stated same number of A's as B's as prerequisite.